# Masking a bit in C returning unexpected result

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, mask

`0x7F000000` is `0111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` in 32 bit binary.
`0x01000058` is `0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 1000`.

When I AND the two numbers together I expect `0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`, but for some reason I get 0.

Here is my code:

```
#define MASK_binop     0x80000000
#define MASK_operation 0x7F000000

int instruction=atoi(line);
if((MASK_binop & instruction)>0)
    printf("binop\n");
else if((MASK_operation & instruction)>0)
    printf("operation\n");
```

Each of the above comparisons keeps returning zero. Is it something to do with 32/64 bits? I'm using 64-bit compiler.

Comment: would unsigned make any difference?

Comment: atoi doesn't understand hexadecimal notation. What does your `line` contain ? "0x01000058", "01000058", "16777304",  or something entierly different ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If line contains "0x01000058" then atoi will return 0 as atoi works with decimal representation, not hex 0x representation. And then the AND obviously is zero. Try to printf the value of instruction.

Answer (score 3):

Do

```
printf("%x", instruction);
```

and ensure that instruction is really what you expect it to be.

you can also do:

```
printf("%x", MASK_binop & instruction);
printf("%x", MASK_operation & instruction);
```

To see what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it and it appears to work as expected.  Do a `printf( "%x\n", instruction);` to show what the value is.

Comment: @Andrejs, Yes.  I built it using the 64-bit version of VS2008 and ran it on a 64-bit machine.